# How to extract specific key, value from PARSE_JSON within Materialized View is redshift

Tags: json, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis

Assuming I expect the following JSON:

```
{
  "key": "value"
}
```

I want to create a materialized view that will show the `key` as a column. The data comes from [Kinesis Streaming Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/materialized-view-streaming-ingestion-getting-started.html#:%7E:text=CREATE%20MATERIALIZED%20VIEW%20my_view%20AUTO%20REFRESH%20YES%20AS%0ASELECT%20approximate_arrival_timestamp%2C%0AJSON_PARSE(kinesis_data)%20as%20Data%0AFROM%20kds.my_stream_name%0AWHERE%20CAN_JSON_PARSE(kinesis_data)%3B) so it has to support incremental refresh as it may contain million of new records per minute. I tried a few ways, one of which:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW kd.streams
AUTO REFRESH NO
AS
SELECT approximate_arrival_timestamp   AS apx_arv_at,
       JSON_PARSE(kinesis_data).key    AS key_value
FROM kd_stream."kinesis-stream"
WHERE CAN_JSON_PARSE(kinesis_data);
```

Which results in:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 5:        JSON_PARSE(kinesis_data).key                      AS...
```

I tried `JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT`, cast to `JSON`, and some other methods.

If I just create the column as json (`JSON_PARSE(kinesis_data)`) it works, but that means I would need to build another MV on top of it. FYI `kinesis_data` is `binary varying`, and `kinesis-stream` is the kinesis stream (not a table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you are trying I assume that kinesis_data is a string/text.  The error you are seeing is because the query parser doesn't know about "key" when it runs.  You see this super value isn't created until run time.  So when it sees "." it doesn't know what to do with this.

If kinesis_data was of type super then using the "." notation would work as the parser knows this is a (potential) part of the super. If you think Redshift should be smarter about this I suspect you will need to submit a case.

Now getting what you want is simple enough but first I need to understand what you mean by "cast to JSON" as JSON isn't a Redshift data type.  I'm guessing you want a super with just a string in it but this isn't clear.

I'm going  to focus on the select query in the MV definition as this is where the issue is located.

Fix #1 - add a with clause.

If we start with the test table defined by:

```
create table test as select '{
  "key": "value"
}' as col;
```

we can extract the value by:

```
with super as (
SELECT JSON_PARSE(col)    AS key_value
FROM test
WHERE CAN_JSON_PARSE(col))
select key_value, key_value.key
from super;
```

Fix #2 - use JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT

Using the same test table as #1 we can:

```
SELECT col, json_parse('"'||JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(col,'key')||'"')    AS key_value
FROM test
WHERE CAN_JSON_PARSE(col);
```

The json_parse and all the quoting here isn't needed if you wanted a string instead of a super.

Lastly as a sanity check here's how the parser handles the "." notation when the table data is a super:

```
create table test2 as select json_parse('{
  "key": "value"
}') as col;

select col.key 
from test2;
```

I hope this helps you get what you need.

============================ UPDATE ============================

Per the comments here's some revised code.

Create test table as varbyte data:

```
create table test as select '{
  "key": "value"
}'::varbyte as col;
```

Make materialized view with code 1:

```
create materialized view public.ttt 
auto refresh no
as 
with super as (
SELECT JSON_PARSE(col)    AS key_value
FROM test
WHERE CAN_JSON_PARSE(col))
select key_value, key_value.key
from super;
```

This works but cannot be incrementally updated due to the extraction of "key" from a super type (untraceable) and likely the use of a cte that also adds some indirection.

Make materialized view from code 2:

```
create materialized view public.ttt 
auto refresh no
as 
SELECT col, json_parse('"'||JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(col,'key')||'"')    AS key_value
FROM test
WHERE CAN_JSON_PARSE(col);
```

This has no incremental update limitations.

Comment: Kinesis stream is `binary varying` not a string. As for the with - it is not possible in MV. I'm getting `Column aliases are not supported.` even if I delete all column aliases.

Comment: This is why DDL is important.  Luckily varbyte to string is a case.  Can you update your question with what you are trying now.  I believe that ctes and subqueries are allowed in a CMV.  I suspect that this issue is elsewhere and the error messaging isn't great.  The message you showed is often a warning about not being able to perform incremental updates to the MV.  Is this the case?

Comment: A quick check shows that RS will automatically cast the varbyte to text for functions that require text.  Also adding the CMV around the query works just fine with the cte.  The warning message is from the extraction of key from a super as RS cannot trace the dependencies through this step so incremental updating won't work  However, the second code option will work for incremental update.  I'll add code to the answer.

Comment: Updated. If you follow that link in the question you will see `"kinesis-stream"` is not a table (therefore no DDL). Also, added that the MV as to incrementally refresh.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  You can get a incrementally update-able MV using JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT and this is of type super.  Is this not what you need?

Comment: I would ask you to test with kinesis stream. No. It does not work. I get `ERROR:  function json_extract_path_text(binary varying, "unknown") does not exist` for the first MV, and `ERROR:  Materialized view over stream could not be created, reason: Column aliases are not supported.` for the second

Comment: Did you cast the varbyte data to text?

Comment: if I add `::text` to `col` in the last example of your answer it works!